# Identical HTML not rendering the same

Tags: html

I have a program that let's people design web pages graphically.  Then hitting Publish creates an html file that is supposed to be an exact copy of what they created. The elements created by the editor are HTML elements.  Publish then gathers up all the elements that have been created and for each one adds it to a string with

```
canvasOuterHTML += clone$[0].outerHTML;
```

So all the styles, text, etc., get put on the string. This string, along with some other information is written to the .html version of the page, and when this .html is loaded into a browser the browser displays the page!

But something is expanding the published page vertically. I've created the simple page below to illustrate.  The first image is the page in the editor. The second image is what the html displays in the browser.

[image]
 [image]

I'm completely stumped because the HTML and CSS for the two markups is exactly the same, so how can one be higher?  I can't even think of a mechanism that would do that.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming your making the editor in HTML / CSS / JS, too? Maybe one of the styles for the editor is affecting the display of the page in the editor. Try disabling all of the CSS in your editor, and see if they match then.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't think it's just the editor that's wrong, though, I think it's the published page too.  If I overlay the 2 screen captures it's clear that it's the line-height that's more on the published page.  The lh  in the editor is 23px and 24px in the published page. A jsfiddle with lh=20px, though,  puts exactly 20px from line to line.   So what would make a browser be careless in setting line-height, not picking the specified 20px but 23px in one case and 24px n the other?